# SharePoint 2010 Workflow Deployment

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

So I'm kinda new to SharePoint Development. I developed a Worfklow on VS2010 an this one worked on the localSharePoint Server. Now When I'm trying to add this Workflow to my extern SharePoint Server it just wont work to assign this workflow to a list.

How i Deploy:

I take the "*.wsp" file from \bin\debug and upload it via the Gallery->Solution. then I acitvate the solution, bute then  i cant find this workflow to assign it to a List.

Thank you

Markus

Comment: You have to package it as a sandboxed solution to deploy locally as mentioned. Follow this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615452(v=office.14).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy your .wsp.

This link can help you for that;

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hmm i just want to add the workflow to my one WebSite, not not the whole sharepoint farm